# Creating Lead through REST API and time in date/time field is 4 hours behind

Tags: rest-api, leads, datetime

I'm working on an integration that creates Leads through the REST API. One of the fields that is updated on create is a date/time and so far every time we send a Lead through the time in this field is adjusted 4 hours back from the time sent through.

Our org setting for timezone is GMT -4:00 so I think Salesforce is seeing the time as GMT and then converting it to our local setting.

Is there some part of the POST request that should be changed that we are missing or is there a setting in Salesforce we don't have right?

Comment: can you post you code whatever you have tried so far.

Comment: Hi ZackB, welcome to SFSE. Please take a moment to visit the [help], scroll through the [tour], and read [ask]. Without seeing the payload in your `POST` request, it is very difficult to offer assistance. Please **[edit]** your post to clarify what you have tried in this regard. Thanks!

Comment: can you post the request payload you are sending

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My apologies for not posting code, I was waiting on info from someone else. I think this was a problem with a missing 'Z' on the date time in the POST. Per this article https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=Data-Loader-Import-data-for-Date-or-Date-Time-field-1327108684799&language=en_US&type=1